# How to convert date time to format Sat Feb 17 2018 13:35:33 GMT+0200 (EET)

Tags: c#

How can I convert DateTime to the following format:

```
Sat Feb 17 2018 13:35:33 GMT+0200 (EET)
```

Comment: Rep of nearly5K and you're unable to google this? Have you let someone else use your account?

Comment: No need to give us information. Do you want to store this in a string or just print in out?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try following :

```
            DateTime date = DateTime.Now;
            DateTime EET = TimeZoneInfo.ConvertTime(date, TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById("E. Europe Standard Time"));
            string dateEE = EET.ToString(@"ddd MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss G\MT+0200");
```